# terminal error when python tries to execute command

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, terminal, os.system

I am trying to run a terminal command using python but i get a terminal error:
"x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal"

I am trying to change my desktop background using python. I have a raspberry pi running latest raspbian.

Running the  command directly in lxterminal it works and changes my background:
"pcmanfm --set-wallpaper /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/bridge_wallpaper.jpg"
and changes my desktop background.

Using os.system("ls -a") works fine. As do other linux system commands such as "mkdir" or "pwd" python has no problem showing me the output in terminal.

I have tried using subprocess call functions nothing has worked so far.
I also have tried making python open a new, different terminal and running the code in the new terminal but also no luck:

```py
os.system('gnome-terminal --command="pcmanfm --set-wallpaper /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/bridge_wallpaper.jpg"')
```

Any thoughts guys? Do i have to start a seperate completely new terminal session? Is it a problem with my syntax? Am i using the wrong python command to execute command in a terminal?

```py
import os,random

random_pic = random.choice(os.listdir('/usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/'))

shell_command = ("pcmanfm --set-wallpaper /usr/share/rpd-wallpaper/" + str(random_pic))

os.system(shell_command)

print("success... wallpaper is changed")
```

Comment: Please delete the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411318/calling-a-terminal-command-through-python-why-does-terminal-give-error-when-pyt

Comment: pcmanfm throws the same error "x-terminal-emulator has very limited support, consider choose another terminal" on Ubuntu 19.10,